# 90 days into beta: where we're at

Tags: discussion

Our beta site has just reached the minimum time for proving its eligibility to become an official Stack Exchange site, so I think it's a good time to discuss how things are going. These are the statistics:

[image]

What these figures tell us is that the site is already very popular in terms of traffic and usage (see visits and questions per day), but as for answers provided we're underperforming. The percentage of questions answered has been dropping since day 1 and the number of so-called *avid users* is still quite low, meaning that only a restricted group of users is sufficiently active.
How do you guys interpret these numbers? Maybe for a new beta they are just awesome and I'm being too critical :)
I'm curious to know your views on how we can:

- encourage users to be more active and increase their reputation;
- improve/moderate/close low-quality questions;
- provide more "restrictive" guidelines to avoid duplicates/off-topic/downright pointless questions.

Thanks for your contributions, and please suggest other points worth discussing.

Comment: https://plus.google.com/105043728733814678193/posts/6ckc41cSyCv

Answer (score 7):

I think we still have a major problem with voting. There's a lot of "unanswered" questions that are actually answered questions with no votes. So I think that contributes a lot to our lack of rep. We need to be more adamant about voting. I know this is difficult to get new OPs to upvote answers to their questions. I'm not sure how we can counter that other than by combing through the unanswered questions and hand out upvotes

Comment: And this needs to be done carefully, because the system will catch votes that are given by the same person to the same person(s) as sock puppet votes.

Comment: I don't agree that the problem would be the lack of voting, rather the lack of answers. As the stats state, they recommend that questions receive 2.5 answers average, but we're significantly below that. I think we'd see a surge in "answered" questions if we had more answers, not if we artificially upvote them.

Comment: Lewis is right, we need more answers per question, not answers with higher amount of votes.